# Spotify iOS SDK SPTDiskCache settings and usage

Tags: ios, spotify

In the Spotify iOS SDK you can configure the player with a disk cache. I have seen examples similar to this:

```
- (void)setupSpotifyPlayer
{
    SPTAuth *auth = [SPTAuth defaultInstance];

    if (self.player == nil)
    {
        self.player          = [[SPTAudioStreamingController alloc] initWithClientId:auth.clientID];

        self.player.playbackDelegate = self;
        self.player.diskCache        = [[SPTDiskCache alloc] initWithCapacity:1024 * 1024 * 64];
    }
}
```

The documentation for [SPTDiskCache](https://developer.spotify.com/ios-sdk-docs/Documents/Classes/SPTDiskCache.html) and the corresponding [SPTDiskCaching](https://developer.spotify.com/ios-sdk-docs/Documents/Protocols/SPTDiskCaching.html) protocol are very sparse and do not have any description of correct usage or settings. The [SPTAudioStreamingController](https://developer.spotify.com/ios-sdk-docs/Documents/Classes/SPTAudioStreamingController.html#//api/name/diskCache) references the `diskCache` property, but again no useful description of usage.

1. What are the correct settings for initializing the disk cache? Why?
2. How is this disk cache used?
3. Can we access offline tracks that have previously been cached?

Comment: Any updates on this?